# google drive application in android to upload photos to the drive.The code is listed below

Tags: android, android-activity, google-drive-api

I wrote code in 3 different classes.

1. First for connection
2. Second for taking images from gallery
3. Third for uploading images to the drive.

I made a `Googleapiclient` object as static in the first class like

```
 static GoogleApiClient getmGoogleapiclient()
     {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
       }  without null value i got  mGoogleApiClient
```

in the 3rd class, while executing this line:

```
Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(Bqdriveactivity.getmGoogleapiclient()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
```

the problem occurs, no error inside the pgm but it won't execute.

This is the code

```
   public class Uploadimage extends Activity 
 {
    private static final String TAG = "Jimmy-android-drive-application";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 0;
//  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;

    public Bitmap mBitmapToSave;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bpobj=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    String images;
    ArrayList<String> stringArray;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_bqdriveactivity);
          stringArray= getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("imagearray");

          if(stringArray!=null){
          Iterator<String> i = stringArray.iterator();
            do 
              {  
                  images=i.next();
                  Log.e("name is: ",images);
                  mBitmapToSave=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(images);
                 if(mBitmapToSave==null){
                      Log.e("ERROR? : ","mBitmap is null");
                   }
                  else
                   {
                      //Log.e("ERROR","not null");
                   }
                    try {
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new myThread());
                        thread.start();


                         } catch (Exception e) {

                           e.printStackTrace();
                         }
          }while (i.hasNext());
          }
                      }

    class myThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            saveFileToDrive(mBitmapToSave);

        }


    }

public void saveFileToDrive( Bitmap bp)  {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");

      final  Bitmap image = bp;
        if(bp==null){
             Log.e(TAG,"bitmap is null");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"bitmap is not null");
        }

           if(Bqdriveactivity.getmGoogleapiclient()==null){
               Log.e(TAG,"null client"); 
           }
           else
           {
           Log.e(TAG,"not null");
           }
```

up to here the code executes

```
             Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(Bqdriveactivity.getmGoogleapiclient()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

             public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "inside drive contents");
                 if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                     return;
                 }

                 Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                 // Get an output stream for the contents.
                 OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                 Log.i("TAG","getoutputstream");
                 // Write the bitmap data from it.
                 ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 Log.i("TAG","before compress");
                 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                 Log.i("TAG","after compress");
                 try {
                     outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                      Log.i("TAG","inside try");
                 } catch (IOException e1) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                 }
                 // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                 // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                 MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                         .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
                 // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                 IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                         .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                         .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                         .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                         .build(Bqdriveactivity.getmGoogleapiclient());
                 try {
                     startIntentSenderForResult(
                             intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                 } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                     Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                 }
             }  
                 });
   }


    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    mBitmapToSave = null;

                }
                break;
        }
    }



                 }
```

Comment: Please provide with some stacktrace occurs.

Comment: hi viewers,
i myself found the solution.my conection object is not connected while entering the above class(3rd class) i specified.it is getting disconnected while entering the onPause method(eg:mGoogleapiclient.disconnect()).i removed the comment and all are working fine.

Comment: please note that code is specified in the first class ie my connection class which is not specified here.
IN A SINGLE SENTENCE I RECHECKED MY CONNECTION.